# Logic Apps creates a file for each copied folder with the same name

Tags: sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure environment with Logic Apps and a storage account. My pipeline moves data from SharePoint to the storage account with a "When a file is created or modified (properties only)" trigger.

Every time my pipeline copies a folder, it also creates a file with the same name in the storage account:
[image: File and folder with the same name]

Here is my Logic Apps pipeline:

1. When a file is created or modified (properties only)
2. Get file content using path (Folder path + file name with extension)
3. Check whether blob exists
4. Delete blob
5. Upload blob to storage container

How can I prevent those files being created per each copied folder?

Comment: We’re flying blind Karem. You’re asking us to help without showing us your flow. It’s imperative to providing a solution so please provide screenshots at a minimum. Also, what have you done to try and correct the issue yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are following the same flow as mentioned, the flow will fail at `Get file content using path (Folder path + file name with extension)` step itself, since SharePoint could differentiate between file and folder.
- `Create Block Blob` Step will be creating additional empty files as because Blob Storage will not consider folders or files as 2 different things.
- It takes both file and folder as blob. So, when you are trying to create a blob inside storage account (which is probably a folder) it will create an additional empty file for folder too.
- After reproducing from my end, to reproduce the same results as yours, I have enabled the Configure run after for `Create Block Blob` Step.

[image]

[image]

Hierarchy in Storage Account:

[image]

Alternatively, if there is no 'Configure run after' in your flow, you can add trigger condition to your logic app trigger. Consider you have folders in SharePoint as below.

```
folder1/f2/f3/sample.txt
```

With the same flow the logic app will be triggering 4 times.

[image]

To avoid such mishaps, you need to mention the below trigger condition in your trigger.

```
@equals(triggerBody()?['{IsFolder}'], false)
```

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: Adding the trigger for folders worked!
@equals(triggerBody()?['{IsFolder}'], false)